# how to get the attribute value by another attribute's value in xpath

Tags: xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serviceOfferings xmlns="http://www.abc.com/aaa" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <serviceOffering type="provider">
        <links>
            <link title="Service Provider" type="application/xml" rel="self" href="https://www.yahoo.com"/>
            <link rel="create" href="https://www.google.com/create"/>
        </links>
    </serviceOffering>
</serviceOfferings>
```

How do I get the `href` value for the link which attribute `rel` is `create`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 0):

The target element is in a default namespace. First, you'll need to register that namespace with your XPath engine. How you do this depends on the tool you're using, which means it's outside the scope of this question (since you haven't told us *how* you're evaluting your expressions).

Let's assume you've registered the namespace to a prefix called `aaa`. Select the desired `link` like this:

```
//aaa:link[@rel='create']
```

Or, more specifically:

```
/*/*/*/aaa:link[@rel='create']
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, in most cases this can also be achieved without registering a namespace, at the cost of reduced readability:

```
/*/*/*/*[name()='link' and @rel='create']
```

This selects all elements whose name is `"link"` (regardless of the namespace they belong to) and that have a `rel` attribute whose string value is `"create"`, and that are grand-grand-children of the top element of the XML document.